# Quill mention : trigger an event when clicking on the list

Tags: javascript, dom-events, quill

I am running Quill Mention, and I want to get the user id when I click on the suggestion list.

The form:

```
<form>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="user_id_field">
</form>
```

The JS:

```
async function suggestPeople(searchTerm) {
   const allPeople = [
      { id: 1, value: "Fredrik Sundqvist" },
      { id: 2, value: "Patrik Sjölin" }
   ];
   return allPeople.filter(person => person.value.includes(searchTerm));
}

const quill = new Quill("#editor", {
    placeholder: "Enter @",
    modules: {
        mention: {
            allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
            mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
            source: async function(searchTerm, renderList) {
                const matchedPeople = await suggestPeople(searchTerm);
                renderList(matchedPeople);
            }
        }
    }
});

window.addEventListener("mention-clicked", function(event) {
    const userId = event.detail.id;
    console.log(userId);
});
```

The event "mention-clicked" is triggered when I clik on a username inside the

```
<div id="editor">
```

But I would like it to be triggered when I click on the suggestion list.

I have tried that instead, with no luck:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   const editor = document.getElementById("editor");
   const suggestionsList = document.getElementById("quill-mention-list");

   if (suggestionsList) {
      editor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         const target = event.target;
         if (target === suggestionsList || suggestionsList.contains(target)) {
            console.log('click');
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Please refer to this onSelect Method.Which will have the info about the added tag.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78199746/21459082

Answer (score 0):

Found it, by retrieving the content of the editor:

```
quill.on('text-change', function(delta, oldDelta, source) {
   if (source === 'user') {
      const editorContent = quill.root.innerHTML;
      const matches = editorContent.match(/data-id="(\d+)"/g);
      if (matches) {
         <....>
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If Trigger is the only thing you need you can make use of **"onClose"** trigger.
This will be triggered on closing of suggestion dropdown.But there is no clicked target avilable in this.

```
const quill = new Quill("#editor", {
    placeholder: "Enter @",
    modules: {
        mention: {
            allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
            mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
            source: async function(searchTerm, renderList) {
                const matchedPeople = await suggestPeople(searchTerm);
                renderList(matchedPeople);
            },
        onClose: () => {
          console.log('on close eve: ');
          },
        }
    }
});
```

As per official Documentation

1. onOpen function--Callback when mention dropdown is open.
2. onBeforeClose function--Callback before the DOM of mention dropdown
   is removed.
3. onClose function--Callback when mention dropdown is closed.

**PS:** *But if you want to make use of clicked target and its properties.You should take it through another approach.Please feel free to comment if thats the answer you are looking for.*