# quill-mention Select Event.How to get Selected mentions from Quill Mention

Tags: angular, quill, react-quill, mention, ngx-quill

Iam Using **Quill mention with ngx-quill**.
Every text edit and formatting is working.
Iam not able to find the **onSelect event of QUILL MENTION LIST**.
What I ultimately want is that to push mentioned objects, which will be selecting from dropdowns, into an array.
mention-clicked and hover is the only event listener available regarding to mention elements.
How to get the selected mentions???

HTML

```
<quill-editor [modules]="{ mention: mentionConfig }" [style]="{height: '300px'}"></quill-editor>
```

Angular TS IMPORTS

```
import Quill from 'quill';
import 'quill-mention';
import { QuillEditorComponent } from 'ngx-quill';
```

TS / JS

```
@ViewChild(QuillEditorComponent) editor!: QuillEditorComponent;


 mentionConfig = {
    allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
    mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
    "toolbar":false,
    source: (searchTerm: string, renderList:any) => {
      // Your mention source logic here
      const values = [
        { id: 1, value: 'Alice' },
        { id: 2, value: 'Bob' },
        { id: 3, value: 'Charlie' },
      ];
      const matches = values.filter(mention => mention.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));
      renderList(matches, searchTerm);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Use onSelect method ,you get the item and insertItem is available.Use editor instance  quillRef.current.editor.getModule('mention').options.onSelect = (
        item,
        insertItem
      )=>{}

Comment: @RajaRamachandran Thankyou.I got that working with onSelect.I have used delta.ops for taking selected tags.But this one is THE solution.Anyway Iam adding my solution also as bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS / JS

```
@ViewChild(QuillEditorComponent) editor!: QuillEditorComponent;


 mentionConfig = {
    allowedChars: /^[A-Za-z\sÅÄÖåäö]*$/,
    onSelect: (item, insertItem)=>{
      console.log(item);//Will have the added suggestion/Tag
     }
    mentionDenotationChars: ["@"],
    "toolbar":false,
    source: (searchTerm: string, renderList:any) => {
      // Your mention source logic here
      const values = [
        { id: 1, value: 'Alice' },
        { id: 2, value: 'Bob' },
        { id: 3, value: 'Charlie' },
      ];
      const matches = values.filter(mention => mention.value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));
      renderList(matches, searchTerm);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I know it was too obvious and direct answer ,but still was not able to find this during my research.
thanks @ RajaRamachandran